# How To Sort Object based on Object's attribute?

Tags: java, hashmap

I got everything else to work except the sort method. I need to sort the Students in the HashMap based on the Student's first attribute. I need the sort method to happen after I added all of the students in the HashMap, not while it's being added.

```
package HashMap;

        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.HashSet;
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class clubMapping {
            HashMap<String, HashSet<Student>> map = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Student>>();

            public clubMapping(String clubName) {
                InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                        "student.txt");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(is);
                while (scan.hasNext())
                    add(scan.next(), scan.next(), Integer.parseInt(scan.next()),
                            scan.next());
                scan.close();
                System.out.println(map);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(map.get(clubName));
            }

            public void add(String last, String first, Integer id, String club) {
                HashSet<Student> set = new HashSet<Student>();
                if (!map.containsKey(club)) {
                    set.add(new Student(last, first, id));
                    map.put(club, set);
                } else {
                    set = map.get(club);
                    set.add(new Student(last, first, id));
                }
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                new clubMapping("Math");
            }
        }

    package HashMap;

    public class Student {
        String last, first;
        Integer id;

        public Student(String l, String f, Integer i) {
            last = l;
            first = f;
            id = i;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return last + " " + first + " " + id;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you shorten it down to pinpoint the error?

Comment: there is no error in the code I have so far, I just need to add the sort method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `TreeSet` instead of a `HashSet` for the student set.  A tree set is implicitly sorted, a hash set is not.

```
public void add(String last, String first, Integer id, String club) {
    TreeSet<Student> set = new TreeSet<Student>(studentComp);
    if (!map.containsKey(club)) {
        set.add(new Student(last, first, id));
        map.put(club, set);
    } else {
        set = map.get(club);
        set.add(new Student(last, first, id));
    }
}
```

But you must define a comparator to use for the sorting, as shown below.

```
private static Comparator<Student> studentComp = new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        return (s1.last.compareTo(s2.last));
    }
};
```

Also, you should probably encapsulate your student attributes in getter/setter methods, rather than accessing them directly as I've done above (as your class currently allows).

Comment: What is the studentcomp in the add method

Comment: It's a Comparator. The TreeSet uses it to compare the Students while sorting.

Comment: It's a custom comparator, supplied to the `TreeSet` constructor as an argument.  This will ensure that everything added to the set stays sorted by the comparator definition (in this case, student last name).  You say that you don't want to sort until **after** adding all students, but this makes no sense because a `HashSet` as you're using now maintains no order anyway, so you lose nothing by maintaining a sort from the beginning.

Comment: Really?  I've done it after many times and it works fine.  However, the post above wasn't meant to imply order one way or another, just to show how to define it.

Comment: @Prasanth Take a look at the constructor for `TreeSet` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Comparator%29