# Referencing an anonymous inner class before its definition

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class

In [a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773662/how-to-sort-object-based-on-objects-attribute/13773705#13773705), I was told that it is wrong to define an anonymous inner class "after" (below) a function which uses it.  However, something like the below compiles and runs fine:

```
public class CompTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>(intComp);
        ts.add(1);
        ts.add(2);
        ts.add(3);
        System.out.println(ts.toString());
    }

    private static Comparator<Integer> intComp = new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            return i2.compareTo(i1);
        }
    };

}
```

What is the official word on this?  My guess is that since `intComp` is `static`, then it is instantiated once when the class `CompTest` is "loaded" (not sure exactly how that load takes place since there is only a main method and no `CompTest` objects are constructed), and therefore when `main()` needs `intComp`, it is available regardless of where in the source file it was actually defined.

And even though it does work (for the above reason or even a different one)... is it bad practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are refering to this comment I believe:

> *"The comparator definition should be before the add code – Bryan Glazer"*

There is no technical reason to put the `intComp` declaration before (or after) the `main` declaration.  It works fine either way.

The only possible reason for putting the comparator earlier is stylistic.  That is, the `intComp` declaration is a static *variable*, and it is *conventional* to declare variables at the start of a class.

<sub>I'm inclined agree with the style point, but it is a minor issue.  Also, if it was me, I'd declare the comparator as `final`, give it a more meaningful name, and use the "constant" naming style; e.g. `INT_COMP` (but more meaningful).</sub>

---

Re Nambari's comment:

> "I think it is bad practice, anonymous class are for limited scope not for global scope."

This is nonsense.  It is quite common for anonymous classes to be used in this way.  Sure, anonymous classes *can also* be used in nested scopes ... and that is one of their advantages ... but that in no way means that *this* pattern is wrong.

Comment: Correct, that is the comment I was referring to.

Comment: Just to get more information, why not go with separate class instead? Isn't it more confusing notation?

Comment: @Nambari - 1) because it makes it harder to read ... 'cos you now have to look in a different source file to find the declaration ... assuming that's what you mean by a separate class. 2) only if you find anonymous classes confusing.  And if that is the case, there are serious concerns with your Java skills.

Comment: @StephenC: Confusing may not be correct word, I meant maintenance.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.  The name was just a lark for this example, I would indeed use a more meaningful name in a real program.  However, the `final` part I had not considered, and it does make sense also.

Comment: @Nambari - it doesn't help maintenance either.  Trust me, I've been reading / maintaining other peoples' Java code for over 10 years.